# What kind of stain is recommended for a weathered antique front door - gel stain or wiping stain?

Tags: wood, staining, varnishing

I have an old weathered front door that I want to sand then stain and then seal with marine varnish.

Should I use a gel stain or a wiping stain?  Would gel stain be better because it's a vertical door so the gel would stick better, and since the door is old and has some surface grooves the gel will smooth over the imperfections?

Or is wiping better because it can get into the nooks and crannies of the detail in the trim?

I don't plan on taking the door off the hinges so something that can be put on while the door is on the hinge would be great.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would be concerned the stain will settle into the cracks and grooves and you will not be able to wipe it off from those spots and they will get extra dark.   Of course, it may look good that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off- nice door !

Either jeld stain or regular wiping stain will work fine *if the prep work is done well*. The prep work will be 90% of this project.

The difference between the 2 stains is mostly about viscosity so yes, the jeld stain is definitely a little thicker bodied which will make it less drip prone. Both stains will be brush applied I imagine. With either stain type you will have a ton of wiping in and then wiping off because of all the intricacy your door has. Another advantage the jeld stain has is that it is far less likely to produce overlap lines. Do not expect the jeld stain to fill in surface cracks that will be the job of the varnish you are applying as a finish.

All in all, either product will work.

Comment: Thanks!  So would you say gel stain would be easier with similar results?

Comment: I do prefer using the jeld stain (purely an opinion). A standard stain will be easier to work into all the details on your door (because it is more liquid) but with more drips and mess and also a higher chance of overlap lines. Probably worth getting small cans of each and sampling how they will work so you can see what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the gel stain would be easier. Use a paint brush to push it into all the cracks/grain. Wipe off the extra stain with a rag before it dries. Let dry completely before the marine varnish. Each coat might take a day to cure. Be prepared to not close the door if possible.